# UIButton in UITableViewCell Not removed from it's superview cell

Tags: ios, iphone

I have trying this task since long time

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}
long row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = items[row];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = alertsTimeArray[row];
cell.textLabel.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 10);
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

NSLog(@">>  %@",alertsTypeArray);
    if (![[alertsTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Critical"]){

    NSLog(@">>  %@",alertsTypeArray);
    UIButton *    reset = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [reset addTarget:self
              action:@selector(customActionPressedForAlertView:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [reset setTitle:@"RESET" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [reset setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:126/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    reset.frame = CGRectMake(250.0f, 22.0f, 70.0f, 30.0f);
    reset.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell addSubview:reset];

   }


cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
return cell;
}
```

```
(void)customActionPressedForAlertView:(id)sender{

UIButton *mybutton =  (UIButton *)sender;
[mybutton removeFromSuperview];

UIAlertView *resetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure to reset alert?" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[resetAlert show];
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
selectedIndex =  indexPath.row;
}
```

But I'm not able to remove the RESET button from it super view cell Please help me.

Every time my alertsTypeArray will fill with two different alerts, "Critical" and "service". If it is service then I need to add reset button or else I shouldn't , if reset button added and the user clicks the resent button then the row should delete, so for the i deleted the one of the alertsTypeArray type , but the reset button is not removing from the tabel , if i load the table view , reset button come's to critical alert.

Thanks,

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Please explain how your program is supposed to function.

Comment: @CaptJak, why so serious?

Comment: If your button's action method is being called, there's no reason that removeFromSuperview shouldn't work. Either that method isn't being called, or you have multiple buttons on top of each other in your cell, and you're only removing the top one. The code you have in cellForRow will add another button when a cell that already has one is reused.

Comment: @CaptJak Evert time my alertsTypeArray will fill with  two different alerts "Critical" and "service"  if it is service the i need to add reset button or else i  shouldn't , if reset button added and the user clicks the resent button then the row should  delete, so for the i deleted the one of the alertsTypeArray type   , but the reset button i not removing for the tabel , if i load the table view , reset button come's to critical alert.

Comment: @rdelmar so what should i do to resolve this issue,

Answer (score 0):

As rdelmar stated, you most likely are removing the button, but you are also probably adding on several buttons to the same cell (since you add without checking to see if it exists first).

Simply check if the button already exists and only add it to the cell if it doesn't.

Give your button an arbitrary tag (like `123`) and check if that tag exists in the cell before adding it.

So change:

```
 if (![[alertsTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Critical"]){

    NSLog(@">>  %@",alertsTypeArray);
    UIButton *    reset = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [reset addTarget:self
              action:@selector(customActionPressedForAlertView:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [reset setTitle:@"RESET" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [reset setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:126/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    reset.frame = CGRectMake(250.0f, 22.0f, 70.0f, 30.0f);
    reset.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell addSubview:reset];

   }
```

To:

```
    if (![[alertsTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Critical"])
{
    NSLog(@">>  %@",alertsTypeArray);
    UIButton *reset = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];

    if (reset == nil)
    {
        UIButton * reset = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [reset addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressedForAlertView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [reset setTitle:@"RESET" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [reset setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:126/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        reset.frame = CGRectMake(250.0f, 22.0f, 70.0f, 30.0f);
        reset.tag = 123;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:reset];
   }
```

Removing the button should be a bit simpler than you have it.

```
(void)customActionPressedForAlertView:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *pressedButton = sender;
    [pressedButton removeFromSuperview];
}
```